# volcanic effects on the climate during Pangaea

Tags: geology, climate, climate-change, paleoclimatology

Which influence does the constellation of the continents have on the global climate? Was the biosphere more susceptible to climatic effects a volcanic eruption may cause during the Permian than it is today?

We know that eruptions of volcanoes can influence the global climate and we know that during the Permian period the continents drifted together to a supercontinent extending from the South Pole along the meridian almost to the North Pole. At such a constellation of the land mass, it's imaginable that an eruption of a volcano may have triggered a chain of effects which caused a change of the global climate which was different than we could expect in our current environment.

Are there any evidences from a palaeontological point of view that such a concentration of the land mass strengthened the rise of the global temperature (which probably killed many species) after the release of greenhouse gas a volcano might have caused?